# java error while parsing xml file from url

Tags: java, xml, json, jdom

I am trying to parse an XML file in java but i am facing a problem. The code is showing an error in the parsing process as if it is getting a JSON File. How can i solve this issue ?

```
URL url2 = new URL("https://api.eancdn.com/ean-services/rs/hotel/v3/list?cid=55505&minorRev=99&apiKey=cbrzfta369qwyrm9t5b8y8kf&locale=en_US&currencyCode=USD&longitude=0.1275&latitude=51.5072&xml=%3CHotelListRequest%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Ccity%3ESeattle%3C%2Fcity%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CstateProvinceCode%3EWA%3C%2FstateProvinceCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CcountryCode%3EUS%3C%2FcountryCode%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CarrivalDate%3E11%2F25%2F2014%3C%2FarrivalDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CdepartureDate%3E11%2F27%2F2014%3C%2FdepartureDate%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfAdults%3E2%3C%2FnumberOfAdults%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoom%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FRoomGroup%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3CnumberOfResults%3E25%3C%2FnumberOfResults%3E%0A%3C%2FHotelListRequest%3E");
InputStream is2 = url2.openStream();

SAXBuilder builder = new SAXBuilder();
Document doc = builder.build(is2);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
Element root = doc.getRootElement();
List<Element> HotelList = 
        root.getChildren("HotelList");
Element Hotel = HotelList.get(0);  
List<Element> SummaryList = 
        Hotel.getChildren("HotelSummary");
Element Summary = SummaryList.get(0);
Element Sum;
for(int f=0; f< SummaryList.size(); f++){
    Sum = SummaryList.get(f);

    sb.append("Hotel ID: " + Sum.getChildText("hotelId") +"\n" + "Name: " + Sum.getChildText("name") + "\n");
    sb.append("HotelRating: " + Sum.getChildText("hotelRating")+ "\n");

}System.out.println(sb);
```

The Error:

```
org.jdom2.input.JDOMParseException: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:232)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:253)
    at org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder.build(SAXBuilder.java:1091)
    at HotelInfo.main(HotelInfo.java:22)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$PrologDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.jdom2.input.sax.SAXBuilderEngine.build(SAXBuilderEngine.java:217)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Have you looked at the actual XML you are trying to parse? It doesn't matter how the XML is generated, but rather exactly what it is when you are dealing with the parsing side.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the returned data using `curl`.  It is JSON, not XML, therefore you cannot parse it this way. Use a JSON parser instead, or figure out the API parameter needed to make the service return XML.